How should I interpret high Pearson but low Spearman correlations in an Industry-driven Dataset?
I have a dataset from an industrial boiler, and I’m analyzing the CO2. We want to understand which features exhibit trends that closely align with the behavior of CO2.
Interestingly, I’ve found a few features with very high Pearson correlation but very low Spearman correlation with CO2. How should I interpret these cases? What does it mean when a feature, like xi, has a high Pearson correlation but a low Spearman correlation with CO2? Isn’t it generally so that a high Pearson correlation would also imply a high Spearman correlation?

Welcome to CV. Since you’re new here, you may want to take our [tour], which has information for new users. Please add [self-study] tag and read its wiki. Have you checked the scatterplots? High Pearson correlation does not necessarily mean high Spearman correlation. As a toy example, we can check the Dataset IV in the Anscombe's Quartet. For this data, Pearson's r is 0.817 and Spearman's rho is 0.5 (not too low but still lower).

@dipetkov Excellent links. Maybe edit so each link is on a separate line? And maybe preface them with something like "see these links"?

A single whopping outlier can make Pearson's correlation arbitrarily close to $\pm 1$ without changing the Spearman correlation at all.  In that sense your question gives us almost no information about your data.  You need to explore them to understand how they might be related.

I think it would also be useful to visualise the clustering structure of the dataset, assessing how strongly the structure is defined by CO2 as compared to other features. For more guidance on exploratory data analysis, consider posting at DataScience.

Frankly, I wouldn't expect DataScience to offer more expertise on EDA than you would find here.

[This more of an extended comment.]
I have two suggestions: First, you will gain a lot of intuition about your data and how to interpret these patterns by making scatterplots of CO2 against (a subset of) features. Select some features where Pearson's and Spearman's correlation coefficients agree and other features where they disagree, and see if you can notice a difference.
Second, similar questions have come up on Cross Validated before and you can learn a lot by reading related threads. Here are some examples:

What does it indicate when the Spearman correlation is a definite amount less than Pearson? Basically explains the situation with Dataset IV in the Anscombe's Quartet.
What could cause big differences in correlation coefficient between Pearson's and Spearman's correlation for a given dataset? Gives some suggestions what to do in the situation where Pearson & Spearson correlations disagree.
What does it mean if the Pearson's correlation is significant but Spearman is not? Makes an argument for using Spearman correlation by default.

